# Restfb returns null message, post is of rich text format

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

Using Restfb, I am trying to retrieve all posts from a certain page. The problem I am running into is that some posts return null for their content, but are not null on facebook.com. These posts that are null contain rich text, in particular, a BOLD title.

The code I have to connect to the page and get the post is:

```
    Connection<Post> detailedPosts = facebookClient.fetchConnection(
    "#############/feed", Post.class);
```

With the following to get it as a list.

```
    List<Post> posts2 = detailedPosts.getData();
```

Comment: AFAIK regular posts on Facebook can not contain “rich text”. _Notes_ however can contain certain HTML tags, but they removed the ability to retrieve notes with API v2.

Comment: Can you please provide a postid the problem occurs. So I can write a restfb test case and have a look at this.

Comment: Postid: 260319714060895_808128732613321. Link to the post: https://www.facebook.com/260319714060895/posts/808128732613321